# An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near '@where'

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(MAX)=''

SET @str='
DECLARE @where VARCHAR(max)=''''

IF 1>2 
BEGIN
SET @where='' Test_Group_Id=1''
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SET @where='' Party_Master_Id=1''
END

SELECT * FROM dbo.Party_Details WHERE 1=1 and @where';

EXECUTE(@str)
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: What do you see when you PRINT `@str` before you try to execute it?

Comment: `WHERE 1=1`? What's the point? That's a complete waste of the optimiser's time and should be removed. Unless you can think of a time when `1=1` is false?

Comment: Actually, I think you really need to explain this a bit better anyway. Your test in your `IF` is `IF 1 > 2`, which will always be false. Why, therefore, do you need dynamic SQL, when your query will akways be `SELECT * FROM dbo.Party_Details WHERE Party_Master_Id=1;`?

Comment: I cannot access the third-party Oasis site that you reference in your comments below - please put a complete repro here.  See [mcve] and [ask] for more details

Comment: Based on the comments the OP has made on several answers, I get the idea this question is an xy question, or at least is completely unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although others have offered workarounds that achieve the apparently desired end-result, here's the actual reason why you're getting the error, in case that's what you meant to ask:

You are trying to do a dynamic sql query inside a dynamic sql query, but you're only doing it halfway.

If you had printed @str instead of executing it, you would see:

```
DECLARE @where VARCHAR(max)=''''

IF 1>2 
BEGIN
SET @where='' Test_Group_Id=1''
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SET @where='' Party_Master_Id=1''
END

SELECT * FROM dbo.Party_Details WHERE 1=1 and @where
```

The code INSIDE of `@str` isn't making any attempt to replace `@where` with the value of `@where` in its final select.

To fully do a dynamic query inside a dynamic query, you have to do the whole string-concat plus EXEC.   So this would work:

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(MAX)=''

SET @str='
DECLARE @where VARCHAR(max)=''''
DECLARE @str2 varchar(max)

IF 1>2 
BEGIN
SET @where='' Test_Group_Id=1''
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SET @where='' Party_Master_Id=1''
END

SET @str2 = ''SELECT * FROM dbo.Party_Details WHERE 1=1 and '' + @where
EXECUTE(@str2)
';

EXECUTE(@str)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this without dynamic sql also. Something like this. And the where 1 = 1 is just silly so I removed it. And of course the 1 > 2 would be replaced with some sort of real condition.

```
select *
from dbo.Party_Details
where 1 = case when 1 > 2 then Test_Group_Id else Party_Master end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(MAX)=''

DECLARE @where VARCHAR(max)=''''

IF 1>2 
BEGIN
SET @where= 'Test_Group_Id=1'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SET @where='Party_Master_Id=1'
END

SET @str = 'SELECT * FROM dbo.Party_Details WHERE 1=1 and ' + @where

EXECUTE(@str)
```

Comment: please do not remove separated part of my query. all in query in dynamic part see my query and find this variale '@strCrDr ' https://oasis.sandstorm.io/grain/HLhEkpxMmdfTw6ABh9LiDD

Comment: @AshishMaurya no-one is removing anything - the people here are showing you how to construct your desired dynamic SQL properly.  Also, I cannot access that third-party Oasis site - please put a complete repro here.  See [mcve] and [ask] for more details

Answer (score 0):

You're missing basics...

EDIT: explanation for OP and Peter

the syntax was broken because the actual `SELECT` statement that runs was

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Party_Details WHERE 1=1 and 'Party_Master_Id=1'
```

That makes no sense for sql server because there is no condition to check after the `AND` operator.

this should work

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(MAX)=''
DECLARE @where VARCHAR(max)=''

IF 1>2 
BEGIN
SET @where='Test_Group_Id=1'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SET @where='Party_Master_Id=1'
END


SET @str='SELECT * FROM dbo.Party_Details WHERE 1=1 and '+@where

EXECUTE(@str)
```

Comment: please do not remove separated part of my query. all in query in dynamic part see my query and find this variale '@strCrDr ' https://oasis.sandstorm.io/grain/HLhEkpxMmdfTw6ABh9LiDD

Comment: My friend im sorry but you should try to explain better. I'm really missing what you're trying to say

Comment: @AshishMaurya `@strCrDr` isn't in your SQL in your question. If you have more SQL than in your question, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50645182/edit) your question, don't post comments on all the answers without any context and expect people to click a link that has no details of what it contains.

Comment: @AshishMaurya no-one is removing anything - the people here are showing you how to construct your desired dynamic SQL properly.  Also, I cannot access that third-party Oasis site - please put a complete repro here.  See [mcve] and [ask] for more details

Comment: i want use in cursor so
SET @str='SELECT * FROM dbo.Party_Details WHERE 1=1 and '+@where
we not set

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
    DECLARE @str VARCHAR(MAX);

set @str= '
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @where VARCHAR(max);
IF 1>2 
BEGIN
 SET @where='' Test_Group_Id=1''
END
ELSE
BEGIN
 SET @where='' Party_Master_Id=1''
END
set @str=''SELECT * FROM dbo.Party_Details WHERE 1=1 AND '' + @where
exec(@str)
'
exec(@str)
```

This works because there is no type conversion the string value that you pass over to the execute function will then work. It is best where possible to define variables outside of the dynamic SQL section.

Comment: Yep I realized after you responded to somebody else and made this clearer.

Comment: please do not remove separated part of my query. all in query in dynamic part see my query and find this variale '@strCrDr ' https://oasis.sandstorm.io/grain/HLhEkpxMmdfTw6ABh9LiDD

Comment: @AshishMaurya no-one is removing anything - the people here are showing you how to construct your desired dynamic SQL properly.  Also, I cannot access that third-party Oasis site - please put a complete repro here.  See [mcve] and [ask] for more details